# MatSort: property name different from matColumnDef -> Not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material-table

Is there any chance to sort a column with matSort in an Angular table where the name of the property differs from the matColumnDef:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>TEST</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let box"> {{box.input.name}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Please share also the sorting code that fails

Comment: Glad you found the solution :-)

Answer (score 3):

solved the problem with the following https://stackblitz.com/edit/mattable-with-sorting-custom?file=app%2Ftable-sorting-example.ts

therefore renamed

```
matColumnDef="name"
```

to

```
matColumnDef="input.name"
```

also in

```
public displayedLoadingPointColumns: string[] = ['input.name', ...
```

added this method in the .ts file

```
sortColumn($event: Sort): void {
    this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
      switch (property) {
        case 'input.name': {
          return item.input.name;
        }
        default: {
          return item[property]; }
      }
    };
}
```

in the html it looks as follows:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="this.dataSource" matSort (matSortChange)="sortColumn($event)">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="input.name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Title</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let whatevet"> {{whatever.input.name}}</td>
  </ng-container>
...
```